# Wordpress PHP within PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to achieve an outcome that combines two plugins in WordPress.

Basically, I am using Easing Slider Pro and Advanced Custom Fields. When the website owner edits a page, I want them to be able to add a slideshow by simply entering the slideshow ID into an Advanced Custom Field called 'slider'.

This is how one would normally add the PHP to display a slideshow:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('easingsliderpro') ) { easingsliderpro( 5 ); } ?>
```

The 5 is an example of a slideshow ID that can be changed.

Here is the PHP for the advanced custom field:

```
<?php if( get_field('slider') ): ?><?php the_field('slider'); ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Both of these work fine by themselves. But I want a way to combine these two pieces of code so that in the page editor the website manager only has to enter the ID of the slideshow. I don't know a lot about PHP and I am often confused by it, but this was my initial attempt:

```
<?php if( get_field('slider') ): ?>
<div id="sliderframe"><?php if ( function_exists('easingsliderpro') ) { easingsliderpro( <?php the_field('slider'); ?> ); } ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It didn't work, I am assuming because you're not allowed to have PHP code within PHP code. Is there any workaround that anyone knows that could make this achievable?

Many thanks.

Comment: PHP code _within_ PHP code should _probably just be_ PHP code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Am I crazy? Can't you just:</strike>

**AHA!**

I think I see the confusion: `the_field` *echoes* the value out, so it gets passed to `easingsliderpro()` as just `true`, and displays the value.

You need to use a function that *returns* the value, so you can pass it to the next function.

In this case, it's `get_field()`:

```
<?php if( get_field('slider') ): ?>
    <div id="sliderframe">
        <?php 
            if ( function_exists('easingsliderpro') ) :
                easingsliderpro( get_field('slider') );
            endif;
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See more in the documentation:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/

Comment: Wait I think I might be crazy - I bet `the_field()` ECHOES the value and that's where the confusion is. Updating answer to use `get_field()` which RETURNS the value (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/)

Comment: Unfortunately this code only outputs the ID of the slider, not the slider itself. I just get a '5' appear on the page, the slider doesn't appear.

Comment: Are you using `the_field` or `get_field`? Either way the value inside them is the same, they are just used differently. If `5` is not what you expect, then it's a problem in the design. Try `print_r(get_field_object('slider'))` and see if that gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Oh awesome, this works perfect since you updated it. Thanks so much willoller!

Comment: No problem. Wordpress's love for functions that echo instead of return has always been a pain IMHO. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put php open close tags within a php open/close tag.
For your code above, this is valid:

```
<div id="sliderframe"><?php if ( function_exists('easingsliderpro') ) { 
  easingsliderpro(the_field('slider')); 
} ?></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one also just results in a single number being output, not the slider itself.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the plugins and their functions, just showing that you didnt need the inner set of php open/close tags :)