# Inserting Flexible ACF php into Easing Slider php

Tags: php, wordpress, slideshow, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Easing Slider Pro for slideshows and Advanced Custom Fields to build a custom page layout. I can't figure out why the ACF & Easing PHP only outputs the ID number of the slider I want to insert into a page, not the slider itself.

I found this old thread, which has the same problem but it's for regular ACF, not a flexible content field: [Wordpress PHP within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002877/wordpress-php-within-php) -- also, the recommended ES output code has changed a bit, like slider 159 would look like:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'easingslider' ) ) { easingslider( 159 ); } ?>
```

Here's my code, which works fine for photos and texts:

```
<?php while(the_flexible_field('flex_field')): ?>
    <?php if(get_row_layout() == 'photo'): ?>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <h2>Photos</h2>
<img src='<?php the_sub_field('photo-stack_image'); ?>' class="img-responsive" />
      <BR><BR>
<img src='<?php the_sub_field('photo-stack_image2'); ?>' class="img-responsive" />
     </div>

<?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'text' ): ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Texts</h2>
         <?php the_sub_field('text_field');?>
    </div>

<?php elseif(get_row_layout() == 'slider'): ?>
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <h2>Sliders</h2>
          <?php if ( function_exists( 'easingslider' ) ) 
            { easingslider( the_sub_field('easing_slider_shortcode') ); } ?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I've tried switching the_sub_field with get_sub_field but that doesn't even output the ID. I'm new-ish to PHP and wouldn't be surprised to learn that I missed something simple, but what? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** Thanks Hobo! Per your suggestions, I tested the ES function (it works), and found that both "echo get_sub_field('easing_slider_shortcode')" and "print_r(get_sub_field('easing_slider_shortcode'))" brought back just the ID number of the slider, with no additional code. I've double checked the names of the flex field, field and subfield and they're all correct.

I don't know if this helps suggests what the problem is, but I added the PHP code around the ES ID number via ACF's admin-side prepend and append feature, but it didn't echo out the code on the page.

**Update Two** That second try did the trick -- thanks Hobo! Here's my final code if anyone has this problem in the future:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <?php elseif(get_row_layout() == 'slider'): ?>
     <?php if ( function_exists( 'easingslider' ) ) {
         $slider_id = (int) get_sub_field('easing_slider_shortcode');
    easingslider( $slider_id );
} ?>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your additional info.  Like I said, I'm confused why it's not working, but there are a couple more things to try.  If they don't work, and there's nothing in your PHP logs, let us know.  I might have some time tomorrow (it's morning here, so that's in 24 hours) and I can download the plugins and have a look.  Hopefully there's not too much difference between Easing Slider and Easing Slider Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `get_sub_field()` is almost certainly what you want.  `the_sub_field()` will output a value straight away; use `get_sub_field()` when you want to use the value in another function.

Now you'll want to debug whether the problem's with the `easingslider()` function or the value returned by `get_sub_field()`.

To check the `easingslider()` function, just replace the ACF function with the value it returns, eg

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Sliders</h2>
    <?php if ( function_exists( 'easingslider' ) ) 
        { easingslider( 159 ); } ?>
</div>
```

If that looks OK, you know the problem's with the value being returned by `get_sub_field()`.  If it doesn't look right, check you're using the right ID.

Assuming the problem's with the value returned by `get_sub_field()`, you'll want to check it's only returning an integer, and not (say) in integer wrapped in extra HTML (the `_shortcode` part of the name worries me on that front).  So this time, just echo the value being returned without calling the `easingslider()` function, eg

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Sliders</h2>
    #<?php echo get_sub_field('easing_slider_shortcode'); ?>#
</div>
```

Then view the generated page source (eg `Ctrl-U` in Chrome), and have a look at what's between the `#` symbols.  If there's anything except the ID, check your field definition and make sure it's only a number.  If there's nothing, try

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Sliders</h2>
    #<?php print_r(get_sub_field('easing_slider_shortcode')); ?>#
</div>
```

which will give you more detail of what PHP is storing. See [the print_r documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

If there's still nothing, check you have the right field name.

If this process doesn't help you find the problem, update your question with what you do find.

**Update**

Thanks for your update.  I'm a little baffled why it's not working, but there are a few more things to try.  I haven't used ACF's admin-side prepend and append feature, so I'm not sure whether the lack of an echoed value is a problem.

First, are there any messages or errors in your PHP logs?  If there are, that might help to debug the problem.

Next, check `easingslider()` can take a variable as an argument.  I can't see why it wouldn't, but I can't see why what you have isn't working...

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Sliders</h2>
    <?php if ( function_exists( 'easingslider' ) ) {
        $slider_id = 159 ;
        easingslider( $slider_id );
    } ?>
</div>
```

If that works, try

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Sliders</h2>
    <?php if ( function_exists( 'easingslider' ) ) {
        $slider_id = (int) get_sub_field('easing_slider_shortcode');
        easingslider( $slider_id );
    } ?>
</div>
```

Maybe there's a type check somewhere in the `easingslider()` code.

Comment: I've updated my question with the final code I used. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please accept my answer (hit the check mark beside it) since it solved your problem.